# How to split a string into three part in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to split a string into three parts no matter the length of the string with JavaScript. Each part does not have to be the same length as the others.

For example:

AABC:

- part 1: AA
- part 2: B
- part 3: C

AABBC

- part 1: AA
- part 2: BB
- part 3: C

aheuc

- part 1: ah
- part 2: eu
- part 3: c

hello world

- part 1: hell
- part 2: o wo
- part 3: rld

Comment: What behavior do you expect, if the string is `"AAA"` for example?

Comment: What is your algorithm for the split? What have you tried and where did it go wrong?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide The characters don't have to be similar. "AAA" 1 = "A" 2 = "A" 3 = "A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this function should capture your intended goal:

```js
function splitStringInThree(string) {
  if (string.length <= 3) return string.split('');
  
  const remainder = string.length % 3;
  const divisor = Math.floor(string.length / 3);
  
  const sep1 = remainder === 2 || remainder === 1 ? 1 : 0;
  const sep2 = remainder === 1 || remainder === 0 ? 0 : 1;
  
  const string1 = string.slice(0, divisor + sep1);
  const string2 = string.slice(divisor + sep1, (divisor * 2) + sep1 + sep2);
  const string3 = string.slice((divisor * 2) + sep1 + sep2);
  
  return [string1, string2, string3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is split a string into three chunks (regardless of patterns or anything) then the below will work for you.*

```
function splitChunks(string) {
    var regex = RegExp(".{1,"+Math.ceil(string.length/3)+"}", 'g');
    return string.match(regex);
}
```

---

What I'm doing is creating a regex function that splits a string into chunks. The only "magic" I'm throwing into here is that I'm setting the chunk length to the length of the string divided by 3 (as you can see in the `regex` variable.

*** The only issue is that it will only work well for string lengths > 5. Some strings of a shorter length will not split into chunks of 3 as there is not enough string to split nicely into 3 chunks.

Examples of output:

```
> splitChunks("abcdefg");
  (3) ["abc", "def", "g"]

> splitChunks("abcdefghijk");
  (3) ["abcd", "efgh", "ijk"]

> splitChunks("abc");
  (3) ["a", "b", "c"]

> splitChunks("abcd"); // :(
  (2) ["ab", "cd"]
```